# How do I generate a cryptographically secure alphanumeric string in Python?

Tags: python, security, google-app-engine, authentication

I'd like to generate alphanumeric authentication tokens in a cryptographically secure way on my Google App Engine Flask server. How can I go about doing that?

Comment: I'm no cryptographer, but if I was doing this, I'd use a CSPRNG, generate a byte array of a certain size and base64 encode it. Something about generating an alphanumeric string "by hand" for an auth token rubs me the wrong way, but maybe it's the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [PyCrypto](https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto), which implements a cryptographically secure version of python's random module. Google App Engine offers this as a library you can include in your App Engine project by adding the following to `app.yaml`:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

PyCrypto is also available outside GAE as a python library.

You can then generate a 32-character alphanumeric string with

```
from Crypto.Random import random

def generate_auth_token():
    """ Generate a 32-char alnum string. 190 bits of entropy. """
    alnum = ''.join(c for c in map(chr, range(256)) if c.isalnum())
    return ''.join(random.choice(alnum) for _ in range(32))
```

Comment: what is `a 32-bit alphanumeric string`?

Comment: Unless this is a toy project, you shouldn't be writing your own authentication code. That said, for this implementation, you'd be better off using the [constants from the `string` library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-constants) and [PyCrypto's `random.sample`](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/) rather than writing your own alphanumeric filter and sampling code -- `random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, 32)`.

Comment: Doesn't sample avoid duplicates? That reduces your key space considerably, you want repeated characters.